# HIghlight integer coordinates in continuous plot

Tags: plotting, visualization

Suppose I have the plot of some function y = f(x):

```
Plot[f(x),{x, x_min, x_max}]
```

Is there any option to highlight all coordinates (x,y) when both of them are integer?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by "integer coordinates". Integer x? Integer f(x)? Or both have to be integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f[x_] := 5 x^2/3

{xmin, xmax} = {0, 10};

pts = Select[
  Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, Ceiling[xmin], Floor[xmax]}],
  IntegerQ[#[[2]]] &]

(* {{0, 0}, {3, 15}, {6, 60}, {9, 135}} *)

Plot[f[x], {x, xmin, xmax}, Epilog -> {Red,
   AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_] := .5 x + (x - 1)^2
```

#### DiscretePlot + ConditionalExpression + FractionalPart

```
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 6}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  Ticks -> {Range[6], Range[0, 30]}, 
  GridLines -> {Range[6], Full}], 
 DiscretePlot[ConditionalExpression[f[x], FractionalPart[f[x]] == 0.], {x, 0, 6}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> False]]
```

[image]

#### MeshFunctions +  FractionalPart

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 6}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {FractionalPart[f@#] &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0.}},
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], 
 Ticks -> {Range[6], Range[0, 30]}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[6], Full}, 
 PlotPoints -> {100, Range[0, 6]}, 
 Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

We get the same picture using the option settings:

```
MeshFunctions -> {# &} (* and *) 
Mesh -> {Select[FractionalPart[f@#] == 0. &]@Range[0, 6]}
```

or

```
MeshFunctions -> {Boole[FractionalPart[#2] == 0.] Boole[
      FractionalPart[#] == 0.] &}  (* and *)
Mesh -> {{1}}
```

**Note:** In the second approach, the option setting `PlotPoints -> {100, Range[0, 6]}` ensures that sampling includes points with integer horizontal coordinates and the setting `Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}` ensures that the end-points are included in mesh calculation.